# Force close in Background Service in android Application

Tags: android, background, android-manifest, android-service

Hi. I have create a background service application following this tutorial http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.com/2010/10/basic-android-background-service.html. But I have an error in the manifest file.

**Error Message**

```
The element type "category" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</category>".
```

I don't know how to create an Android background service. Any guidance on that is appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.javaorigin.android.sample.service" android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0">
  <application icon="@drawable/icon" label="@string/app_name">
   <service class=".MyService" name=".MyService">
     <intent-filter>
       <action android:value="com.javaorigin.android.sample.service.MY_SERVICE"
               android:name=".MyService" />

       </intent-filter>
   </service>
  <activity android:name=".SampleAction"
             android:label="@string/app_name">
       <intent-filter>
           <action name="android.intent.action.MAIN">
           <category name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER">
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
```

Comment: The error message is quite clear . You have forgot to add end "/" <action name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
           <category name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no big problem in your manifest file. That tutorial seems like old and you need to do few changes to get rid of errors. Like the forward slashes to end action and category tag, instead of attribute name use android:name, move the uses-sdk before application tag(where Lint prefer it). Thats it !

Try This :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.javaorigin.android.sample.service" android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0">
   <uses-sdk minsdkversion="8"/>
   <application icon="@drawable/icon" label="@string/app_name">
       <service class=".MyService" android:name=".MyService">
         <intent-filter>
           <action android:value="com.javaorigin.android.sample.service.MY_SERVICE"
                   android:name=".MyService" />

           </intent-filter>
       </service>
      <activity android:name=".SampleAction"
                 android:label="@string/app_name">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>

   </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: my Application is working fine.But i need to get the latitude and longitude inside of service class,but i cannot to create the location manager.how to do

Comment: Thank you Sourb am getting problem again

Comment: The android:name attribute in receiver's action helped me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to the Service element.  Your XML is malformed; any tags that do not contain nested elements must terminate on the same line with a slash.  Here is the corrected block:

```
<activity android:name=".SampleAction"
         android:label="@string/app_name">
   <intent-filter>
       <action name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Note the slashes after MAIN and LAUNCHER.  Without these, the parser thinks you are leaving the tag open to nest children underneath it.

Comment: if i do like this i got error in manifest file Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - error: Error parsing XML: mismatched tag
 - The element type "uses-sdk" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</
  uses-sdk>".

Comment: Sounds like your missing a closure on that tag as well.  It's hard to verify since that part of your manifest is not posted.  ANYWHERE you have a tag that doesn't wrap other tags, make sure it's properly closed as described.

Answer (score 0):

Copy paste this in your manifest:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.javaorigin.android.sample.service" android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="1.0">
      <application icon="@drawable/icon" label="@string/app_name">
       <service class=".MyService" name=".MyService">
         <intent-filter>
           <action android:value="com.javaorigin.android.sample.service.MY_SERVICE"
                   android:name=".MyService" />

           </intent-filter>
       </service>
      <activity android:name=".SampleAction"
                 android:label="@string/app_name">
           <intent-filter>
               <action name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
               <category name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
     </application>
    </manifest>
```

Comment: i got three errors Tag <service> missing required attribute name.Tag <action> missing required attribute name.Tag <category> missing required attribute name.if i apply this code i got error like this

Comment: Have you configured your manifest file just as given in the link? I mean the link that you've provided.

Comment: i paste  ur manifest only.please give any working example for android background service

Comment: http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/01/basics-of-android-part-iii-android-services/              http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html               http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html  Try these